# Add arbitrary amount of tags per object property in a data enter chain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects that looks like the following:

```
all_data = [
 {  
    title: "Hello", 
    slices: { 
        A: 50, 
        B: 70, 
        C: 40
     }
 },
 {  
    title: "Goodbye", 
    slices: { 
        A: 100, 
        B: 80, 
        C: 50
     }
 },
 {  
    title: "My title", 
    slices: { 
        A: 100, 
        B: 80, 
        C: 50,
        D: 200
     }
 },
```

//etc..
    ]

How could I create `n` groups of an arbitrary number of rectangles appropriately scaled to match the amounts each slice has? I've tried the following but I just don't know how to proceed further.

```
d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.data(all_data)
.enter()
.append("g")
.whatDoIDo()
```

I'm not sure how I inflate each entry in the data chain to an arbitrary number of rect tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to iterate over the slices object, and construct an array which is used as part of new data join.

For example, assuming the same data set you provide in the question, you can create a nested svg and g structure using the following code. The second data join uses the data that is already joined to the g.title elements:

```
    let svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")

    let titles = svg.selectAll(".title")
      .data(all_data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
        .attr("class", "title")

    let slices = titles.selectAll(".slice")
        .data(function(d) {
          let arr = []
          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(d.slices)) {
              // create an array using the key and value from the slices object
              arr.push([key, value]);
            }
          return arr
        })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
        .attr("class", "slice")
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.